# Augmented function signature's parameters inferred as any

Tags: typescript, types, module-augmentation

I'm trying to augment an interface of a package `tizen-tv-webapis`, which is out of my control.

That interface owns a property that is a function. That function has a signature with the second parameter of type `object`.

```js
interface AVPlayPlaybackCallback {
    ondrmevent?(type: AVPlayDrmType, data: object): void;
}
```

I'd like to set it to be a narrowed set of properties instead of a wide generic object, as we saw the API seems to return that specific shape.

```js
// overrides.d.ts

import type { AVPlayDrmType } from "tizen-tv-webapis";

declare module "tizen-tv-webapis" {
    export interface AVPlayPlaybackCallback {
        ondrmevent?(type: AVPlayDrmType, data: {
            name: string;
            message: string;
        }): void;
    }
}
```

Typescript seems to be able to see the file I created containing the augmentation.

However, when I try to create an object compliant with the interface, it suggests me the signature, but both the parameters automatically become of type `any`.

```js
const AVPlayListeners = {
    ondrmevent: (type, data) => {
//               ^^^^  ^^^^  ---> any
    };
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've created a repro-case here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bbiuze?file=overrides.d.ts

I cannot understand why it says it is any while the signature is pretty much the same.
Having to specify the parameters makes the augmentation useless.

Of course, without the augmentation, the parameters are inferred correctly.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES2015", "ES2017.Object", "ES2018.Promise", "ES2016.Array.Include"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "node_modules/<organization>/types"
        ],
        "types": ["node"],
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "packages/*/node_modules", "packages/*/dist"]
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a plaintext [mre] without pseudocode (e.g., `...`), and note that screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  The goal is that others can copy and paste the code into their own IDEs and get to work on the problem, without needing to clear up problems you're not having (syntax errors) or transcribe pictures to text.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz I've edited and added a repro case. I decided to leave the screenshots as, IMHO, they provide only more information about what I'm saying, although they are not essential now to understand the issue. Let me know if this is fine for you or if should I change anything else. Thx.

Comment: So your problem is just that you didn't annotate `AVPlayListeners`?  [Annotating makes that problem go away](https://tsplay.dev/WJrOrW).  If that's your issue, it seems easy enough to address.  If that's *not* your issue, what is?

Comment: The problem is that Intellisense seems to not be able to infer the correct types when I use module augmentation. Even if I do annotation (I tried before, I forgot to write it), `type` and `data` are still considered `any`.

Comment: The behavior seems to be different if augmentation is placed in the same file as where it is used... https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQGoAUA2BDAngEShABVcwBTAGhQx1yzwCNsBjAawGFtNNn24AvnABmUCCDgAiGMABe5AHYBaGADclAd3LMwwAM6SA3AFgAUGYAm5Fjijk4ICBYCume9LmKV6rTv2TEMzg4YAUYcihhVns0Bno6Pk5uXlY2QNNg4IgFCyJyVUUYAH4AChgycgAuGjjCEgrqC2wYbGqEIMzghWwQKrg9GChQgHMTDM6Hcj09bGG+gaGFUY7ggQBKatUIYAsx1bMBMzMWbIGaugAZfXCFCL1q2Lo4xK4eRLgAXnSsnLyCsOqZQacCaLTWnwAfOkAPTQibwhHBAB6RQ6h1MAjGZiAA

Comment: Your link shows `AVPlayDrmType` for `type` and `object | { name: string; message: string;}` for `data`.  I don't see `any`.  Module augmentation looks like it works as intended, according to that link.  Your stackblitz seems to have the same issue even if you *don't* do any augmentation at all (see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g9uwby?file=index.ts)), implying that something else is going on.  Right now this doesn't seem to be a [mre] because it can't be reproduced.  What am I missing? Could you demonstrate the issue in some other way?

Comment: Exactly: playground shows that augmentation seems to be working when everything is placed in the same file. When augmentation is made through two files, something feels to be going on.

Yeah, I see what you say: stackblitz seems to not be reading the dependencies, hence no completion nor augmentation.

If I run [the code on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-playground-export-forked-zjzym), it seems to be fine, so there must be something else going on, as you say.

Comment: I tried to compare and merge my tsconfig with the CodeSandbox one, and found out it seems fault of the missing `compilerOptions.strict: true`, but I'm looking around to try to understand why it matters so much.

It seems to be a missing `noImplicitAny` (which, I know, is loaded through strict mode), but it feels so weird, but seems like it forces compiler to ditch the any for good...

Comment: So module augmentation is a red herring, right?  Maybe we should close this as not reproducible … unless you’d like to edit the question significantly

Comment: @jcalz yeah, I'll add my tsconfig on the main question and answer to my question, so that it will be there for future reference. Thank you

Comment: It's not just "add", it's also "remove any references to module augmentation", right?

Comment: MA is the final goal and the context, so maybe it should remain there. Maybe the title is a little bit misleading and should be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

As per what has been highlighted in the comments, it seems the issue was a missing `noImplicitAny: true` in the `tsconfig.json`.

By adding it, it will the possibility for parameter to be `any` and, therefore, the compiler is forced to show the signatures.